# call shell command from python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this shell command that I want to call from python

```
frontend='test'
instance_list = subprocess.call(['sudo gcloud compute instances list | grep -v TERMINA | grep +'frontend'+ | awk '{ print $1 }''])
```

I'm getting this error

```
    instance_list = subprocess.call(['sudo gcloud compute instances list | grep -v TERMINA | grep +'frontend'+ | awk '{ print $1 }''])
                                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Drop the `+` concatenation (old syntax) and use [string formatting](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling an external command from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
frontend='test'
instance_list = subprocess.call(['sudo gcloud compute instances list | grep -v TERMINA | grep '+frontend+' | awk \'{ print $1 }\''])
```

You just did the string concatenation wrong: the plus needs to be outside of the quotes...
And the quotes for awk probably need to be escaped...

Comment: okay now I'm getting error in this
awk '{ print $1 }''])
                                                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: see my edit: probably you need to escape the quotes around awk (\' instead of ')

Answer (score 0):

You should put the plus signs outside the quotation marks:

```
instance_list = subprocess.call(['sudo gcloud compute instances list | grep -v TERMINA | grep '+frontend+' | awk '{ print $1 }''])
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think the problem is in the way you arranged your quotations and concatenation sign (+)

Concatenation works like: `'Hello' + variable + 'world'`

Or when it is about escaping quotes inside (Which is probably not your case)
You can use triple quotes like `xxx.call([''' You are free to use single quotes inside here ''']);`

---

For your case, this can help:

```
instance_list = subprocess.call(['sudo gcloud compute instances list | grep -v TERMINA | grep ' + frontend + ' | awk '{ print $1 }''])
```